# Unable to replace the parameters value in json object

Tags: python

I am trying to replace the value of varaible in json object but I am not able to do so.I want to replace the value of a datetime in json_input varaible but as of now datetime is getting concatenated

```
json_input='{"provider_code":"test","provider_resource_id":{"name":"test","value":"test"},"provider_account":"123","kpis":[{"kpi":"kpis","value":"80","unit":"%","datetime":""}]}'


newjson = {}
try:
    decoded = json.loads(json_input)

    # Access data
    for x in decoded['kpis']:
         if not (x['datetime']):
               x['datetime']="2019-07-05T18:17:08.257Z"
             newjson=json_input+x['datetime']
except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
    print("JSON format error")
print(newjson)
```

```
*Actual*
new json = {"provider_code":"aws","provider_resource_id":{"name":"app_arn","value":"arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1:802878444238:application/mcms-eb-test"},"provider_account":"802878444238","kpis":[{"kpi":"aws.elasticbeanstalk.health_status","value":"80","unit":"%","datetime":""}]}2019-07-05T18:17:08.257Z

*Expected*
new json='{"provider_code":"test","provider_resource_id":{"name":"test","value":"test"},"provider_account":"123","kpis":[{"kpi":"kpis","value":"80","unit":"%","datetime":"2019-07-05T18:17:08.257Z"}]}'
```

Comment: Your **Actual** and your **Expected** don't match up besides the datetime part. There's a whole bunch of aws stuff that shouldn't even be showing up based on the code you provided.

Comment: Could you wrap the json with ``` ? (same as your code). It would greatly help comparing the responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
json_input = '{"provider_code":"test","provider_resource_id":{"name":"test","value":"test"},"provider_account":"123","kpis":[{"kpi":"kpis","value":"80","unit":"%","datetime":""}]}'

try:
    decoded = json.loads(json_input)
    # Access data
    for item in decoded['kpis']:
        if not item['datetime']:
            item['datetime'] = "2019-07-05T18:17:08.257Z"
except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
    print("JSON format error")
print(decoded)
```

Comment: thank you but this will work if under kpis array object there is only one item

Comment: thank you but this will work if under kpis array object there is only one item 
for eg [{"kpi":"kpis","value":"80","unit":"%","datetime":""}]

if there are multiple items in array then I think probably it will not work

[{"kpi":"kpis","value":"80","unit":"%","datetime":""},{"kpi":"kpis2","value":"80","unit":"%","datetime":""}]

Comment: **edited the code** check now it will work for multiple items, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you're writing `json_input` to `newjson`, when you really want to be writing `decoded` to `newjson`, as `decoded` is the object that you're modifying. `json_input` never gets modified, it is only used to create the JSON representation in Python. Furthermore, the `+x['datetime']` doesn't help with anything, and is probably what's causing that added datetime at the end of your `newjson`.

Instead of `newjson=json_input+x['datetime']`, try `newjson = decoded.dumps()`.

Comment: I am getting this error while trying newjson=decoded.dumps()

Comment: @UmeshKumar So edit your code to show what's going on